# Which space operators public or private, outside of NASA, allow usage of their space imagery?

Tags: nasa, photography

[NASA does not copyright their images](https://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/guidelines/index.html) and allows usage of their photos for free for many uses. There are a few restrictions on commercial use, primarily to keep current staff out of commercials. Otherwise they are very permissive.

Are there any other space agencies or operators who provide space exploration photos either uncopyrighted, as in NASA's case, or with licenses that are free for some types of use? (Such as educational use on this site for example)

Answer (score 1):

SpaceX photos on their [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/spacex/) are in public domain with no copyright. It was covered by many news sites in [2015](https://www.theverge.com/2015/3/20/8262525/spacex-images-public-domain-creative-commons).

Comment: This would be a good answer if not for an important error - SpaceX releases its images under a Creative Commons license, not public domain.

Answer (score 1):

ESA has an open access program that shared data freely, among other things sentinel-2 satelite images with a lisence that allows comersial use. A free registration is needed.

Link to their access hub below
https://scihub.copernicus.eu

Comment: That's great to know! Do you have a link for a site that explains that? It's always better to add supporting links to statements, and in this case I'd be really interested in checking that out further. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh sure, I will link the access page https://scihub.copernicus.eu